# Show icon by using notify.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, notifications

I'm using notify.js. All custom styling works fine but icon doesn't show. 
Background-image works fine but what i want to show an icon tab next to notification text.Is there any way to implement ?You can find my code below
thanks again.

```
$.notify
.addStyle('foo', {
    html: "<div>"
        + "<div class='clearfix' >"
        + "<div class='title' data-notify-html='title'/>"
        + "<div class='buttons' align='middle' >"
        + "<button class='yes' data-notify-text='button'></button>"
        + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>",
    classes: {
        superblue: {
            "color": "#3A87AD",
            "background-color": "#D9EDF7",
            "border": "6px solid blue",
            "border-color": "red",
            "white-space": "nowrap"
            /* "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
            "background-position": "left top",
            "background-size": "25px",
            "background-image": "url('edda.png')"  */
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.notifyjs-foo-base .yes', function () {
    //hide notification
    $(this).trigger('notify-hide');
});

$.notify({
    title: '<h5>Would you like some Foo ?</h5>',
    icon: "image.png",
    button: 'Oke'
}, {
    style: 'foo',
    className: 'superblue',
    autoHide: false,
    clickToHide: false,
    position: 'bottom right'
});
```

Comment: If you check notify.js documentation, there doesn't seem to be an option for adding icons, the way you added. You could use an icon directly on the HTML itself. Where you want to add the icon?

Comment: I want to add  to the left width:%30 height:%100

Comment: i try to add html but it doesn't worked:: 
 ....                                                                                                               
  + "<div class='clearfix' >"
  + "<div><img src='assets/img/icon-big/info2.png'></div>"

Comment: Icon not loading or it doesn't look good?

Comment: I tried below and it loaded successfully. Thank u very much.    + "<div class='clearfix' >"
             + "<img src='assets/img/icon-big/info2.png' class='pull-left gap-right' style='float:left' >"

Comment: No problem, glad your issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much four your interest.